# Clearing repeated values within a row in a selected range

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first time here

I have a code that can remove and repeat values that were once merged within a selection range, so that i can apply filter to data. (see below)

```
Sub mergefiltro()

If MsgBox("select the desired range ?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

 Dim MergedCell As Range, FirstAddress As String, MergeAddress As String, MergeValue As Variant

 Application.FindFormat.MergeCells = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   Do

     Set MergedCell = Selection.Find("", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchFormat:=True)

     If MergedCell Is Nothing Then Exit Do

     MergeValue = MergedCell.Value

     MergeAddress = MergedCell.MergeArea.Address

     MergedCell.MergeArea.UnMerge

     Range(MergeAddress).Value = MergeValue

   Loop

 Application.FindFormat.Clear
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Filter application

Selection.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

This code will repeat values that were once in one sigle cell that was merged with others.

Now, I can't find a way to continue (within the same selection) to clear repeated values ONLY within a row... In other words: I don't want to clear all repeated cell values in a downwards direction (column wise), only to find and clear all repeated cell values to the right of the excel sheet (row wise direction).

I´ve come across this:

```
Sub FindDups()

ScreenUpdating = False

FirstItem = ActiveCell.Value

SecondItem = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value

Offsetcount = 1

Do While ActiveCell <> ""

If FirstItem = SecondItem Then

ActiveCell.Offset(Offsetcount, 0).Value = ("")

Offsetcount = Offsetcount + 1

SecondItem = ActiveCell.Offset(Offsetcount, 0).Value

Else

ActiveCell.Offset(Offsetcount, 0).Select

FirstItem = ActiveCell.Value

SecondItem = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value

Offsetcount = 1

End If

Loop

ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

But this code does exactly the oposite of what i want: Clear's the repeated values within the columns. What i want is one code that clear the repeated values in a row (to the right side cells).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line from your first sub:

```
Range(MergeAddress).Value = MergeValue
```

to

```
Range(MergeAddress).Columns(1).Value = MergeValue
```

Comment: Nice. Worked ;) Thks

Answer (score 0):

I use a variant with a list on one sheet and on data base a filter, that filter

' delete Macro
'dont show srceen
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'
'List of exception on A1 title and a2,3,4,5 to erase
    Sheets("Exception List").Select
'count exceptions

```
d = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Exception List").Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
```

'activate data base to filter
  Sheets("1. Raw Data").Activate

'count data base data ( a3 beacuse mine start at a3, use whatever you need)
  F = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("1. Raw Data").Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 2
  'loop for each exception

```
For i = 2 To d
'exception loop taking
  Sheets("Exception List").Select
Criteria1 = Range("a" & i).Value

Sheets("1. Raw Data").Select
 'filter x exception in loop at data base ( A to Z in my case)
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$Z$" & F).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
    Criteria1
  'down one of visible rows ( form header to first visible data)
  Range("a3").Select
   With Worksheets("1. Raw Data").AutoFilter.Range
     Range("a" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(3).Row).Select
```

End With

```
   'select all data with exception
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Select
    'erase exeptions
Selection.delete Shift:=xlUp
'erase filter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$Z$3").AutoFilter Field:=5
```

'next exception
    Next i

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


'by christian marcos
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   sorry now on code everything
 > 'delete Macro dont show srceen
    > 
    > Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    > 
    > 
    > 'List of exception on A1 title and a2,3,4,5 to erase
    > 
    >  Sheets("sheet1").Select
    > 
    > 'count exceptions
    >    
    >     
    >     d = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Exception List").Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    >      
    >     'activate data base to filter   Sheets("1. Raw Data").Activate
    >       'count data base data ( a3 beacuse mine start at a3, use whatever you need)   F = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("1. Raw
    > Data").Range("A3", Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 2   'loop for
    > each exception
    >   
    >     For i = 2 To d
    >     'exception loop taking
    >       Sheets("Exception List").Select
    >     Criteria1 = Range("a" & i).Value
    >     
    >     Sheets("1. Raw Data").Select
    >      'filter x exception in loop at data base
    >     ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$Z$" & F).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
    >         Criteria1
    >       'down one of visible rows ( form header to first visible data)
    >       Range("a3").Select
    >        With Worksheets("1. Raw Data").AutoFilter.Range
    >          Range("a" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(3).Row).Select
    >           End With
    > 
    >        'select all data with exception
    >     Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Select
    >         'erase exeptions
    >     Selection.delete Shift:=xlUp
    >     'erase filter
    >     ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$Z$3").AutoFilter Field:=5 'next exception
    >     Next i
    >     
    >     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    >     
    >     
    >     'by christian marcos
```